# How to easily set up multiple accounts in mutt?

Tags: mutt

I want to use mutt with multiple accounts.  I would like to use different smtp servers for sending email via ssmtp. One internal provided by the company (imap is supported) and one for my private emails (gmail).

Answer (score 2):

At least in mutt 1.5, you can use `send2-hook` to change configuration values based on the sender address for each message. [From the documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#send2-hook):

> `send2-hook` is executed after `send-hook`, and can, e.g., be used to set parameters such as the $sendmail variable depending on the message's sender address.

While I have not tried it myself, it sounds like a combination of this, ssmtp that you mention, and getmail to download mail from your Gmail account, should do nicely. You may want to throw in procmail as well to do client-side mail sorting.

For easier handling of multiple sender addresses, I myself have the following in my mutt configuration:

```
alias f__1 Me <my.one@address.example.org>
alias f__2 Myself <another@address.example.com>
alias f__3 I <somewhere@else.local>
macro compose <esc>f "<edit-from><kill-line>f__<tab><search>another@address.example.com<enter>"
```

With this in place, I just hit `escape f` in the compose screen to change the sender address, and it defaults to the one I most often use. Partly for historical reasons, I use a folder-hook to set [`$smtp_url`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#smtp-url), but from the sound of the documentation it should be trivial to use `send2-hook` instead.

The one thing I have *not* found a trivial way of handling is signatures. You can use folder-hooks to set the value of $signature on a per-folder basis, but that's about as close as I have been able to (or more accurately, bothered to) get.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Kjörling's answer I was able to get my Mutt sending from multiple accounts, each with their own SMTP config.

First the `msmtp` config. There's nothing special here, it's just two accounts set up following their [docs](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtp.html).

```
$ cat .msmtprc 
defaults
tls on
tls_trust_file [redacted]
logfile [redacted]
domain serverdomainexample.tech

account example
host smtp.example.com
port 587
auth on
from user@example.com
user user@example.com
password correct-horse-battery-staple

account example2
host smtp.example2.net
port 587
auth on
from user2@example2.net
user user2@example2.net
password correct-horse-battery-staple-2

account default : example
```

Next, the `mutt` config.

```
$ cat .mutt/muttrc
...
set sendmail      = '/usr/bin/msmtp'
set realname      = 'User'
set use_from      = 'yes'
set envelope_from = 'yes'
set from          = 'user@example.com'
alternates          '(user@example.com)|(user2@example2.net)'
macro compose <esc>1 '<esc>f^UUser <user@example.com><enter>'
macro compose <esc>2 '<esc>f^UUser2 <user2@example2.net><enter>'
send2-hook '~e user2@example2.net' "set sendmail = '/usr/bin/msmtp -a example2'"
...
```

With the macros, I can select my outgoing address when on the mail compose screen by entering `<esc>+#`, where `#` is the number for the address I want.

i.e.
`<esc>+1` for `user@example.com`
`<esc>+2` for `user2@example2.net`

With the `send-hook2` line, mutt will check if the `Sender` address matches `user2@example2.net`.
When it does, `msmtp` will be invoked with the `-a example2` flag, at which point it will use the `example2` account configuration instead of the default.